# How to write lists as input filters to mysql table in django model instance

Tags: django, django-views

I have below fields in my Django model

```
class cube(models.Model):
    pid = models.IntegerField()
    lc = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sid = models.IntegerField()
    st = models.IntegerField()
    wid = models.IntegerField()
    wt = models.IntegerField()
```

I have below input set coming from clients

input_set1 object -

```
[{"sid":1,"st":7},{"sid":7,"st":5},{"sid":5,"st":9},{"sid":2,"st":7}]
```

input_set2 object -

```
[{"wid":3,"wt":5},{"wid":1,"wt":7},{"wid":4,"wt":8},{"wid":2,"wt":5},{"wid":5,"wt":5}]
```

Below is my requirement which is in mysql notation :

```
select pid,lc from cube
where (((sid=1) AND (st>=7)) AND ((sid=7) AND (sid>=5)) AND ((sid=5) AND 
(st>=9)) AND ((sid=2) AND (st>=7)))
AND (((wid=3) AND (wt>=5)) AND ((wid=1) AND (wt>=7)) AND ((wid=4) AND 
(wt>=8)) AND ((wid=2) AND (wt>=5)) AND ((wid=5) AND (wt>=5)))
```

Input {sid,st} and {wid,wt} sets can contain upto 10 items each -
like {sid,st} can be upto 10 for each input and same with {wid,wt}

How can I write this sql notation in django ?

I would like to use the input parameters as lists like below in my view, so that it would be generic for the input sets -

```
input_set1=[{1,7},{7,5},{5,9},{2,7}]
input_set2=[{3,5},{1,7},{4,8},{2,5},{5,5}]

fieldsReq=['pid','lc']
queryset=cube.objects.values_list(fieldsReq).filter(reduce(operator.and_, (Q(sid__contains=x) for x in ['3', '5', '6']),(Q(rt__contains=x) for x in ['4', '8', '3']))) #Am not sure how to write the condition here
```

I would like to map input_set1 to {sid,st}
and input_set2 to {wid,wt}, but found it difficulty in writing.

How can I achieve this in Django notation to get the fields from mysql table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt for `sid`, it should apply to `wid` as well.

```
from django.db.models import Q

# original input
input = [{"sid":1,"st":7},{"sid":7,"st":5},{"sid":5,"st":9},{"sid":2,"st":7}]
# a list of Q objects
queries = [Q(sid=i['sid'], st__gte=i['st']) for i in input]
# 'AND' all conditions
sid_query = reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, queries)

fieldsReq=['pid','lc']
queryset=cube.objects.values_list(fieldsReq).filter(sid_query)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ShangWang!

Comment: Hi Shang Wang, How can I write OR operation for this requirement.. select pid,lc from cube
where (((sid=1) AND (st>=7))  OR ((sid=3) AND (st>=5)) OR (...)

Comment: queries = [Q(sid=i['sid']) | Q(srt__gte=i['srt']) for i in input]

Comment: Is this the correct way of writing OR operation but for the combination of sid and st sets ?

Comment: Just change the `&` in my answer to `|` in the `reduce` statement.

Comment: Thank you.. For some reason, values_list() is not working.. I see all the result set even after specifying only two fileds required from the database..What am I missing ?

Comment: If you do `filter` first then `values_list` after, does that solve your problem?

Comment: Hi @ShangWang , Requesting you to kindly check query  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969599/django-python-lamba-expression-for-case-statement-and-groupby-having?noredirect=1#comment55698756_33969599